# Mocking Registry and File System

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, filesystems, registry

If I am to write unit tests for reading/writing/creating registry entries or files, my understanding is that I should not be using real registry and file system but should mock them in a light weight manner.

What mocking framework would you recommend for mocking these in C# desktop/WPF style apps?
What would be a good introductory reading into this topic?

Comment: Mocking static classes like `Registry` and `File` is not easy (or possible?) unless you purchase e.g. TypeMock. If you can change the code you're testing, consider wrapping the actual registry and file accesses in a class that implements an appropriate interface - `IRegistryXXX`, `IFileXXX` - so then you can mock the interface and the unit tests can check that you're making the appropriate calls at the right time.

Comment: @stuardt Would it be possible to have a simple example.  I am new to this, not sure I follow.  Much appreciated.

Comment: no problem, see answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, here's an example.

Given these classes:

```
public interface IRegistryActions
{
     bool WriteValue(string key, string value);
}

public class RegistryActions : IRegistryActions
{
    public bool WriteValue(string key, string value)
    {
        // pseudocode
        // var key = Registry.OpenKey(key);
        // Registry.WriteValue(key, value);
    }
}
```

And this class that uses them: the class which will perform the actions is passed to the constructor in this example, but could as easily be a property. This means that whenever you want to actually use the class in your actual code, you can explicitly pass a class that implements `IRegistryActions` as a parameter - e.g. `var exampleClass = new ExampleClass(new RegistryActions());` - or alternatively default to the actual implementation if passed null, i.e. `this.registryActions = registryActions ?? new RegistryActions();`

```
public class ExampleClass
{
     private IRegistryActions registryActions;

     public ExampleClass(IRegistryActions registryActions)
     {
          this.registryActions = registryActions;
     }

     public bool WriteValue(string key, string value)
     {
          return registryActions.WriteValue(key, value);
     }
}
```

So in your unit test you want to verify that the call is made with the right parameters. How exactly you do this depends on what mocking framework you use, which is generally either a matter of personal choice or you use what's already used.

```
[Test]
public void Test_Registry_Writes_Correct_Values()
{
     string key = "foo";
     string value = "bar";

     // you would normally do this next bit in the Setup method or test class constructor rather than in the test itself
     Mock<IRegistryActions> mock = MockFramework.CreateMock<IRegistryActions>();

    var classToTest = new ExampleClass(mock); // some frameworks make you pass mock.Object

    // Tell the mock what you expect to happen to it
    mock.Expect(m => m.WriteValue(key, value));

   // Call the action:
   classToTest.WriteValue(key, value);

   // Check the mock to make sure it happened:
   mock.VerifyAll();
}
```

In this you're asserting that your class has called the correct method on the interface, and passed the correct values.

Comment: That clarifies it, thank you.  Which mocking frameworks would you recommend?

Comment: I personally couldn't recommend one - the one I like isn't really maintained any more, and I don't like the one everyone else seems to like.

Comment: Thank you for your great help and answer StuardtI did some more investigation and came up with using the combination of what you suggested above with RhinoMocks.  Much appreciated~

Comment: Here's one I've been using for my own projects: https://github.com/dwmkerr/dotnet-windows-registry